# Fermat's Little Theorem not useful as $p\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I'm having trouble with some questions of which Fermat's little theorem doesn't seem to simplify enough. For questions such as

What is $10^{41} \text{mod}\;49$? I get stuck. Since $$10^{48}\text{mod}\;49=1\text{mod}\;49$$ $$41=(48-7)$$ therefore the answer is $$10^{-7}\text{mod}\;49$$ But now I have no idea how to simplify this answer down. I know the inverse of $10 \text{mod}\;49$ is $5\text{mod}\;49$. Will I have to calculate $5^7$ with brute force and then take it modulo $49$? Or is there a simpler way to do it? If I have to do it by brute force then this would make fermat's little theorem not very useful as $$a^k \text{mod} \; p, \;p\rightarrow \infty$$ As once you reduce the power so $k<p-1$ then $k$ will still be extremely large.

Thanks

Comment: $49$ is not a prime. Euler's generalisation of Fermat's theorem applies, and $\varphi(7^2) = (7-1)\cdot 7 = 42$.

Comment: Ah of course thanks a lot :)

Comment: Well you can also check if $a^{p-1}$ is the smallest integer that gives remainder 1,basically any prime divisor of $p-1$ can give remainder 1.

Comment: @DanielFischer My statement that fermat's little theorem being useless as p is large, is that correct? Say I was taking modulo $503$ instead of $49$. Then I can't express $41$ in terms of multiples of $502$.

Comment: Well, you need exponents that are at least not much smaller than $\varphi(m)$ to benefit from Euler's theorem, in that sense it becomes less useful for large $p$. But for theoretical considerations, it is as useful for gigantic primes as for smallish primes.